# Magento 2 Adding extension attributes to Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterface

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

I'm trying to add a custom track url to the trackings, using extension attributes, i added these in `extension_attributes.xml`

```
  <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterface">
    <attribute code="track_url" type="string"/>
  </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackCreationInterface">
        <attribute code="track_url" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
```

Cleared the generated codes and caches, interfaces are populating correctly, I used `\Magento\Sales\Api\ShipOrderInterface::execute` to save the shipment:

```
            $this->shipOrderService->execute(
                $order->getId(),
                $items,
                $data->isCustomerNotify(),
                false,
                $comment,
                [$data->getTracking()]
            );
```

and the `$data->getTracking()` has data looking like this:

```
  {
    "track_number": "1Z37X3X41217934386",
    "title": "ups",
    "carrier_code": "ups",
    "extension_attributes": {
      "track_url": "blah"
    }
  }
```

So everything looks fine and the extension attributes data are passed fine down to `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractExtensibleModel`, however in `Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject` which is what `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackExtension` extends from, `$data` becomes an empty array, i still can’t figure out why this is happening, i’m in dev mode and shouldn’t need to run DI or something like that, any ideas?

Comment: Actually, you should provide all the files or at least describe what have you've done so far. From your description I couldn't see how you retrieve and save the data

Comment: @Jimmy updated my question with how i'm saving the shipment. Since i'm using scalar attributes i don't think i'll need to add any plugins? When i dove into the code, it should be able to save the data but somehow extension_attributes got stripped at Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject constructor

Comment: "Since i'm using scalar attributes i don't think i'll need to add any plugins?" this is not correct, you have to manually touch the extension_attributes, they don't get saved into db automatically